# Mongoose/MongoDB: Get all records per day

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've tried all solutions I could find on here, but I am still coming up with 0 records and not sure why!

##### Scenario:

Get call records for each day. Output total calls for each day

##### The code:

```
  const startOfMonth = new moment().startOf('month');
  const yesterday = new moment().subtract(1, 'day');
  const now = startOfMonth.clone();

  while (now.isSameOrBefore(yesterday)) {
    const today = now.clone();

    const cdrIns = await CDRIn.find({
      createdAt: {
        $gte: today,
        $lt: today.add(1, 'day')
      },
    });

    console.log(`There were ${cdrIns.length} calls on ${today.toDate()}`)
    now.add('1', 'day');
  }
```

##### Sample of a call record in mongodb

[image: Same CDR in mongodb]

##### Results:

```
There were 0 calls on Thu Sep 22 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
There were 0 calls on Fri Sep 23 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
There were 0 calls on Sat Sep 24 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
There were 0 calls on Sun Sep 25 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
There were 0 calls on Mon Sep 26 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
There were 0 calls on Tue Sep 27 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
There were 0 calls on Wed Sep 28 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
There were 0 calls on Thu Sep 29 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Momentjs mutates original objects when `add`ing, it does not create a new one.

So you need to clone the object; otherwise, you're sending a command to MongoDB saying, "get me the documents that are created between tomorrow and tomorrow (same date)", which is clearly not what you want.

```js
const cdrIns = await CDRIn.find({
  createdAt: {
    $gte: today.clone(),
    // without cloning, .add(...) changes the object above as well
    $lt: today.clone().add(1, 'day').toDate()
  },
});
```

Comment: Perfect. After logging what you said, I see that now!

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the dates using `toISOString()`:

```
const cdrIns = await CDRIn.find({
  createdAt: {
    $gte: today.toISOString(),
    $lt: today.add(1, 'day').toISOString(),
  },
});
```